# Arrival with Etihad Preclearance at T4 and then connecting flight from T2

Tags: transit

Arrival with Etihad Preclearance from AUH at T4 and then have a connecting flight from T2  (Delta) to Tampa.
Can we take the inter terminal bus from T4 to T2 immediately after deboarding.
Or is it necessary to exit T4 and then take train / shuttle bus to T2.
Please advise
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Which airport are you talking about?

Comment: Please don't just use airport codes. Unless they're very famous, people have to look them up. Also, they're very susceptible to typos: if you wrote "Abu Dgabi", people would immediately know that you meant Abu Dhabi; if you wrote "AUG", people would think you were flying from Augusta, Maine.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Except they didn't put AUG, they put AUH, which it's likely anyone who can answer the question will know is Abu Dhabi

Comment: The mystery airport is obviously JFK.

Comment: @Doc You seem to have completely missed the point I was making. This time, the asker seems to have got the code correct. Next time, they might not -- it's very easy to make typos. But, if they'd used the airport name, a typo wouldn't have mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Your flight will generally(*) land as if it was a "domestic" flight, and you will be let out into the standard terminal 4 departures area.  From there you will be able to catch the Delta Shuttle to terminal 2 if required.  You will NOT need to re-clear security.

(*) Generally, because occasionally pre-cleared flights will still be forced to go through some level of immigration or customs control on arrival in the US.  This is rare, but can happen.  In this case you would need to re-clear security in either T4 or catch the airtrain to T2 and re-clear security there.